# Dart, how to listen for websocket close on server side?

Tags: events, websocket, dart

I see that client side websockets have an [onlClose](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.WebSocket#id_onClose) stream which is useful, but why isn't there a complimentary onclose stream on the server side [websocket](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.WebSocket)? I would like to be able to clean up my websessions on the server side when the web socket closes but Im not sure how to detect that event occuring on the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server-side [WebSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.WebSocket) API is a Stream. That means that to listen on data, you can do the following:

```
websocket.listen((data) {
  // Do something with data.
}, onDone: () {
  // No more data - read-direction was closed.
});
```

Where the `onDone` callback is invoked, when the WebSocket is closed.

Comment: Is there a way to listen for websocket close without listening to data?